# Sending image from JS client to Java/Springboot server via fetch returns error 500

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot, image, fetch-api

I need to send (upload) an image file from the web client (html+javascript) to the server (java/springboot) that will then store it.

On the client side I have created a form, of course

```
<form action="" name="missionForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate>
  <fieldset>
    <div class="field">
      <label>
        <span style="font-weight:bold">Mission name</span>
    <input data-validate-length-range="3" name="name" id="name" required="required" />
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <label>
    <span>Mission image (png):</span>
    <input type='file' class='optional' name='loadImage' id='loadImage' accept='image/png'>
      </label>
    </div>
 </fieldset>
</form>
```

The form is read below via javascript, who sends the request via fetch

```
document.forms[0].onsubmit = function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
   var imageFile = document.forms['missionForm']['loadImage'].files[0];
   
   const test = fetch(url+"/api/saveImage", {
    method: 'POST',
        body: imageFile,
    });
}
```

On the server side (Java / Springboot), I have created the following method in the Controller class

```
@PostMapping(value="/api/saveImage")
public void saveImage(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile multipartFile) throws SQLException{
     String fileName = StringUtils.cleanPath(multipartFile.getOriginalFilename());
     System.out.println("filename is "+fileName);   
}
```

When I launch this, I get error 500 on the client.
On the server side, I get the following error "org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Current request is not a multipart request"

I do not understand why. Can anybody help? I am sure I am missing something silly here.
Thanks!

I tried "forcing" the content-type in the fetch request, but I only get a different error

```
   const test = fetch(url+"/api/saveImage", {
    method: 'POST',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',},
        body: imageFile,
    });
```

and the error is "org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadException: the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found"

Answer (score 0):

You should use **form data**. Additionally before uploading the file from the client, you can use **postman** and you can generate file upload code from there. Here is code:

```
var myHeaders = new Headers();

var formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append("file", fileInput.files[0], "<PATH>");

var requestOptions = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: myHeaders,
  body: formdata,
  redirect: 'follow'
};

fetch("http://localhost:8082/api/file/upload", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

Postman example:

[image]